# Why does the page shift upwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Do you have any idea why the page shifts upward when I click the arrows (the slideshow navigators arrows) down at the bottom?
It's been bugging me for a while now.

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow ">
<div class="slides">
<img class ="slide active-slide" src="http://gearnuke.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/GTA-5.jpg">
<img class ="slide" src="http://cdn.wegotthiscovered.com/wp-content/uploads/gta5.jpg">
<img class ="slide" src="http://www.igta5.com/images/official-artwork-trevor-yellow-jack-inn.jpg">
<img class ="slide" src="http://cdn2.knowyourmobile.com/sites/knowyourmobilecom/files/styles/gallery_wide/public/0/67/GTAV-GTA5-Michael-Sweatshop-1280-2277432.jpg?itok=nKEHENTW">
</div>

<div class="dots-container">
<ul class="slider-dots">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow-prev" ><<</a>
    <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
    <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow-next" >>></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slideshow{
background-color:#000;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
position:relative;
}

/*image slides*/
.slides{
height:100%;
max-width:100%;

}

.slide{
display:none;
margin:2em;
max-width:70%;
max-height:100%;
}


.active-slide {
display:inline;
max-width:70%;
max-height:100%;
}

/*dots*/
.slider-dots{
text-align:center;
width:100%;
font-size:1.5em;
padding:1%;
}

.dots-container{
padding:1em;
}

.slider-dots li{
display:inline;
}

.arrow-prev, .arrow-next{
font-size:16px;
color:rgb(77, 151, 201);
margin-left:1.8em;
margin-right:1.8em;
font-weight:bold;
}

a.arrow-prev:hover, a.arrow-next:hover,a.arrow-prev:active, a.arrow-next:active
{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;}

.active-dot{
color:#fff;
}
```

I have read multiple threads, but it seems there's no concrete solution to this.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zLd58yo/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order and then force it to scroll to the bottom of the page in this way it will stay at the bottom

```
nextSlide.fadeIn(2300).addClass('active-slide').show();
currentSlide.fadeOut(2300).removeClass('active-slide').hide();
$(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

You can take a look at here http://jsfiddle.net/wvgqnzf9/

Comment: @Justplayit94 you should also try simple css approach answer below in post

Answer (score 3):

For these two lines:

```
nextSlide.fadeIn(2300).addClass('active-slide').show();
currentSlide.fadeOut(2300).removeClass('active-slide').hide();
```

What's happening is you remove the tile, so the page shrinks... then you add one back in so it extends.  However, when it shrinks, everything moves up to accommodate it.  The experience you are getting is because it's happening faster then you can perceive.

Try either reversing the order:

```
currentSlide.fadeOut(2300).removeClass('active-slide').hide();
nextSlide.fadeIn(2300).addClass('active-slide').show();
```

Or if that causes flickering, giving the parent container an absolute height.

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors in your jsfiddle, so if you fix it, you have working app. Fix it just add jquery and bootstrap.css in resource section

I've attached working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zLd58yo/4/)

So html should be just:

```
<body>
    <div class="nav navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="pull-left">  <a href="#"><li>Team</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Learn more</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>

            </ul>
            <ul class="pull-right"> <a href="#"><li>Learn more</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
                <h3>WELCOME TO SAN ANDREAS</h3>

            <p>Prepare to make your dreams come true...
                <p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actors">
<span>TEAM</span>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://cdn2-b.examiner.com/sites/default/files/styles/image_content_width/hash/92/f5/92f51c2146c471daad1002221888f4d3.jpg?itok=MExy-qsb"> <span>MICHAEL</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://cdn2-b.examiner.com/sites/default/files/styles/image_content_width/hash/71/92/7192e2b9c8b6a24e3c9d824942799228.jpg?itok=LVyYEoB4"> <span>TREVOR</span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://media.rockstargames.com/rockstargames/img/global/downloads/buddyiconsconavatars/v_franklin_256x256.jpg">   <a href="#"><span>FRANKLIN</span></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow ">
        <div class="slides">
            <img class="slide active-slide" src="http://gearnuke.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/GTA-5.jpg">
            <img class="slide" src="http://cdn.wegotthiscovered.com/wp-content/uploads/gta5.jpg">
            <img class="slide" src="http://www.igta5.com/images/official-artwork-trevor-yellow-jack-inn.jpg">
            <img class="slide" src="http://cdn2.knowyourmobile.com/sites/knowyourmobilecom/files/styles/gallery_wide/public/0/67/GTAV-GTA5-Michael-Sweatshop-1280-2277432.jpg?itok=nKEHENTW">
        </div>
        <div class="dots-container">
            <ul class="slider-dots">    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow-prev"><<</a>

                <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
                <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
                <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
                <li class="dot">&bull;</li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow-next">>></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix. set min-height of `slides` container.

```
.slides {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px; // set as per your requirement
}
```

Your slides are `fade`ing `out` meaning they are going out of DOM so causing a hole and reducing height of document and thats why its scrolling up and then next slide `fade`ing `in`. so you need to keep the container intact meanwhile, so have some fixed min height to it.

Comment: Hmm, one more thing, if you can help me. In the slideshow, when I'm going tru the images, if one is smaller than the other, or vicevirsa, the div keeps resizing. Any way I could stop it from doing that?

Comment: If you want to avoid resizing then set height of div  `height: 450px;` //something that you want to have